# BindingSource dispose takes too long

Tags: c#, winforms

I Create a form with a `datagridview` and 2 bidingsource witch one set as datagridview datasource and another set as comboboxcolumn in datagridview

when I cloase form and `Dispose` method try to dispose second bindingsource take too long time about 50 seconds

Can any one help me?

Comment: Also, what are those bindingsources(what collections they represent) and how huge are they? Are they related? And have you tried to use second binding source not in DGV, but on standalone control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experience that some times if multiple `combo box columns` that connect to one `bindingsource` can reduce dispose time of binding source
for this columns my solution is to set column datasource manualy to `datatable` that is the `DataSource` of `BindingSource`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you a simple crazy solution that I used some times
Delete all binding source from form and add them again